# What's the difference between angular-cli and @angular/cli on npm

Tags: angular, npm

There are 2 angular cli packages available on npm:

[angular-cli](https://www.npmjs.com/package/angular-cli) which is currently at 1.0.0-beta.28.3

[@angular/cli](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@angular/cli) which is currently at 1.0.0-beta.31

What is the difference between these 2 packages, and which is the right one to use for a new project?

The angular docs aren't particularly clear here. https://cli.angular.io/ says to npm install -g angular-cli, while https://github.com/angular/angular-cli says to npm install -g @angular/cli

Answer (score 19, accepted):

`@angular/cli` is the new package, which name is according to another Angular 2 modules names like `@angular/common`, `@angular/router` and so on.

And also `@angular/cli` requires `Node 6.9.0` or higher, but `angular-cli` requires `Node 4` or higher. So `@angular/cli` with Node 4 will not work.