# Difference between @angular/cli and angular-cli

Tags: javascript, angular

Is there any difference between

> npm install -g @angular/cli

and

> npm install -g angular-cli

Comment: Refer discussion from https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42154789/whats-the-difference-between-angular-cli-and-angular-cli-on-npm

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes it is. The latter is deprecated according to its package page https://www.npmjs.com/package/angular-cli and shouldn't be used on new projects.